# Why does my recursion never terminate in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

```
let qrec=Queue.create ()

let rec queueaddrec1 n=
 if n==1 then
  Queue.add 1 qrec
 else
  Queue.add n qrec;
  queueaddrec1 (n-1)

let ()=
 queueaddrec1 5;
 Queue.iter print_int qrec;
```

VScode told me the following line will never return. I don't why. When I ran it I got a endless loop.

```
queueaddrec1 5
```

If I write this:

```
let rec queueaddrec2 n=
 if n>1 then
  Queue.add n qrec;
  queueaddrec (n-1)
 else
  Queue.add 1 qrec
```

I get another error:

```
This expression has type 'a but an expression was expected of type 
('b->'b Queue.t->unit)->int->int Queue.t->'a
The type variable 'a occurs inside
('a->'a Queue.t->unit)->int->int Queue.t->'b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a code formatting tool: your indentation is lying to you.
Correctly indented and removing the use of `==` (which is not the equality that you want), the first version of your function reads:

```
let rec queueaddrec1 n=
 if n=1 then
  Queue.add 1 qrec
 else
  Queue.add n qrec;
 queueaddrec1 (n-1)
```

You need parentheses to make the whole sequence

```
Queue.add n qrec; queueaddrec1 (n-1)
```

part of the `else` branch.

Your second version is not syntactically valid, correctly indented and without superfluous spaces it reads as

```
let rec queueaddrec2 n=
 if n>1 then
  Queue.add n qrec;
 queueaddrec (n-1) else Queue.add 1 qrec
```

with a keyword `else` appearing outside of any `if ... then ...` .

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to octachron's answer, the root cause here is that OCaml's if/then/else has a higher [precedence](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/expr.html) than `;`. Perhaps somewhat confusingly, the match and function constructs have a *lower* precedence, so the following does work without use of parentheses to group the expressions.

```
let rec add n = 
  match n with 
  | 1 -> Queue.add 1 qrec 
  | _ -> 
    Queue.add n qrec; 
    add (n - 1)
```

Or:

```
let rec add = function 
  | 1 -> Queue.add 1 qrec 
  | n -> 
    Queue.add n qrec; 
    add (n - 1)
```

Now, since in either case you add the current number, and only if it's `1` do you not recurse, you might write:

```
let rec add n = 
  Queue.add n qrec;
  if n <> 1 then add (n - 1)
```

Consider that even with these fixes, your function fails to terminate unless `n` is `1`. Starting with an int less than `1` will still give unbounded recursion.

You might also achieve this with sequences, offloading the logic for the recursion onto the sequence, and then simply adding that sequence to the queue.

```
let count_down f t = 
  let rec aux c () =
    if c < t then Seq.Nil
    else Seq.Cons (c, aux (c - 1))
  in
  aux f 

let add n =
  Queue.add_seq qrec (count_down n 1)
```